# Resize AWS LVM volume

Tags: amazon-web-services, lvm, amazon-ebs

I have successfully increased the space on AWS EBS volume.

```
# lsblk
NAME         MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
nvme0n1      259:0    0   64G  0 disk 
├─nvme0n1p1  259:1    0 63.9G  0 part /
├─nvme0n1p14 259:2    0    3M  0 part 
└─nvme0n1p15 259:3    0  124M  0 part /boot/efi
nvme1n1      259:4    0    2T  0 disk 
└─main-var   254:0    0  996G  0 lvm  /var
```

How can I add the 1T on `nvme1n1` to `main-var` `lvm`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Show the current situation:

```
lsblk
pvs
df -h
```

Tell LVM to extend to the full size of the physical device:

```
pvresize /dev/nvme1n1
```

Show again to see changes:

```
pvs
```

Now you see PFree has increased:

```
vgs
```

`VFree` should have also increased. Extend your volume so it uses that space:

```
lvextend -L +1T /dev/vgname/lvname
```

Show the new volume size:

```
lvs
```

Now you have to resize your filesystem with either `resize2fs`, `xfs_growfs`, etc utility.

Comment: Thanks! pvs not showing me new space dazzled me.

Comment: I have found in the past that with some AMIs if you reboot the server the extra disk space is added automatically. I don't recall which distro this was with.

Comment: unlike debian where it never detects the new size until you reboot

Comment: Thanks, this solution worked on my EBS volume with LVM Type